# How to use Sass Eyeglass with Webpack?

Tags: sass, webpack, eyeglass

I would like to use [Sass Eyeglass](https://github.com/sass-eyeglass/eyeglass) with [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). I have found very little information about it and is rather frustrating because I'm sure it can be done.

Has anyone had any success using it?

Comment: were you ever able to get Eyeglass working with Webpack? Trying to do the same thing...

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get eyeglass working with sass-loader in recent webpack.

Eyeglass injects its own options for sass which you can in turn pass as options to sass-loader:

```
[...]
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    include: config.paths.assets,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style',
      publicPath: '../',
      use: [
        `css?${sourceMapQueryStr}`,
        'postcss',
        `resolve-url?${sourceMapQueryStr}`,
        {
          loader: `sass?${sourceMapQueryStr}`,
          options: eyeglass({
              // sass options...
              includePaths: ['/share/scss/'],
              eyeglass: {
                // eyeglass options
              }
            })
        }
      ],
    }),
 },
 [...]
```