# Unable to config vue-loader with Eyeglass

Tags: webpack, sass, vuejs2, vue-cli, eyeglass

I want to import the eyeglass-spriting, normalize-scss, and compass to my project. I have read the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696767/how-to-use-sass-eyeglass-with-webpack) to config webpack with Eyeglass to:

```
// https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/extract-css.html
return {
  css: generateLoaders(),
  postcss: generateLoaders(),
  less: generateLoaders('less'),
  sass: generateLoaders('sass', { indentedSyntax: true }),
  scss: generateLoaders('sass', eyeglass({
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules/')],
    eyeglass: {
      modules: [{ path: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules/normalize-scss') }]
  }
  })),
  stylus: generateLoaders('stylus'),
  styl: generateLoaders('stylus')
}
```

It results in errors:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors

 error  in ./src/app.vue

 Module build failed:
 undefined
 ^
       File to import not found or unreadable: normalize-scss.
 Parent style sheet: stdin
```

Does anyone succeed?

Update: package.json
The normalize-scss is already in control. I find it in the ./node_modules. When I remove the Eyeglass it works by importing normalize-scss directly in the main.js.

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "unit": "jest --config test/unit/jest.conf.js --coverage",
    "test": "npm run unit",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "normalize-scss": "^7.0.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^21.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "eyeglass": "^1.3.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "jest": "^22.0.4",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "^0.3.0",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-class-component": "^6.2.0",
    "vue-jest": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "vuex-class": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```